# CSS issue in ASP GridView with too long text

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I'm displaying on my ascx control a gridview that allows to edit data directly. One of the field is a text field that can go up to 50 characters. If I reach this limit and try to edit the cell it looks as follow :

[image]

Which is correct. However when I try to edit another cell it results in the following :

[image]

The "Mettre à jour" button falls appart and the gridview overlap on the right.

I've try to overcome this with css using : overflow, add margin or padding, text align etc. So far nothing has helped me overcome this and I've run out of idea. Any help would be great. Thanks

Using inline:block on the button has come closer to what I need (I would like it like on the 1st screenshot) :

[image]

The code of my `<asp:GridView>`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSurveillancesActives" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="odsSurveillancesActives" EnableModelValidation="True" 
    style="margin-right: 1px" 
    onrowupdated="GridViewSurveillancesActives_RowUpdated" 
    onrowdatabound="GridViewSurveillancesActives_RowDataBound" 
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" CellPadding="5" 
    onrowdeleted="GridViewSurveillancesActives_RowDeleted" Font-Size="Small" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreationDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
            HeaderText="Date de création" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="CreationDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ParamName" HeaderText="Secteur" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ParamName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Début" SortExpression="ValidFrom">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="gridViewDateDebut" class="datepicker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ValidFrom", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ValidFrom", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fin" SortExpression="ValidTo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="gridViewDateFin" class="datepicker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ValidTo","{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ValidTo", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commentaire" SortExpression="Comment">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Comment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you using templatefields? If so, show your aspx markup.

Comment: @TimSchmelter here you go

Answer (score 0):

try add style to button

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: So far its the closest to what I need I've been. However I don't get why can simply get it on the same line.